# Print element from array if its not zero

Tags: arrays, c

I want to print an array in c, but only if the specific element of this array is not zero.

Lets assume, `foo` looks like this `12345678900000000000123` i want only print `123456789123`.

```
int foo[512];
for (i= 0; i < 512; i++) {
    if (foo[i] != '0') {  // This is not working
        printf("%d ", foo[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `if (foo[i] > 0)` instead of  `if (foo[i] != '0')`. Your `foo` is `int` array  not a `char` array.

Comment: @SudhirOjha oh well, that was an easy one, thanks!

Comment: The problem is you invoke *Undefined Behavior* by accessing elements of the array `foo[]` when the value of those element are *indeterminate*. All bets are off. You must initialize any variable with *automatic storage duration* before attempting to access the value.. `int foo[512] = {0};` will initialize all elements zero. Otherwise, you have to assign a value to each element before attempting to read that value.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your condition is bad.

```c
if (foo[i] != '0')
```

whit this, you test whether the `foo[i]` is equal to a **character** 0 and not a **number** 0
for fix this use this condition

```c
if (foo[i] != 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has two problems.

1. You didn't initialized the array `foo` and `foo` has storage-class `auto`. The elements contain arbitrary garbage values. Using them in the loop invokes [*undefined behavior*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984).
2. `'0'` is not equal to `0`. `'\0'` is equal to `0`. But better use `0` as you only want `0` in its integer nature.

Surrounding integers in apostrophes make them *character constants* which have specific value. Most likely these values belong to the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character set. `'0'` for example has the ASCII value `48`.

So

```
if (foo[i] != '0')
```

is high-probably equivalent to

```
if (foo[i] != 48)
```

on your system.

---

Side Note:

```
int foo[512];
for (i= 0; i < 512; i++)
```

You use two times the hardcoded value `512`. This technique is susceptible for failures. Better use f.e. a macro constant instead, which ensures that the values are equal:

```
#define SIZE_ARR 512
...

int foo[SIZE_ARR];
for (i= 0; i < SIZE_ARR; i++)
```